# Jquery Validation plugin Error messages on Bootstrap 5.x popovers

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-5

I am using jquery validation plugin with bootstrap 5.x version popovers, but not able to figure out the right solution, please help any one ?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of your problem

Answer (score 0):

After my long research, i found a answer for jquery validation plugin error messages on bootstrap 5.x popovers

```
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
                return bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(value).hide();
            });
            return $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
                bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance(value.element, {
                    trigger: "manual",
                    placement: "bottom",
                    content: value.message,
                });
                bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(value.element)._config.content = value.message;
                bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(value.element).setContent();
                return bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(value.element).show();
            });
        }
    });
```